# ¿Cómo crear una página de opciones en Inno Setup?

Tags: pascal, inno-setup, pascalscript

Necesito crear una página para mi instalador que contenga radio buttons con las opciones de:

- Instalar
- Reparar
- Desinstalar

Soy completamente nuevo en Inno Setup les agradecería sus respuestas muchas gracias.

Comment: podrias aclarar porque el manual de ese sistema no te ayudo con esto? esas opciones no vienen por defecto al correr el instalador por segunda vez?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es fácil, se tiene que realizar en la sección `[Code]`
Primero que nada se crea la variable de la página

```
[Code]
  var
    InstallTypePage : TWizardPage;
```

Seguido en el constructor `InitializeWizard` creamos la página de esta manera:

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
  begin
    InstallTypePage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpSelectDir,'Texto1', 'Texto2', 'Texto3', True, False);

    //Crea los radio buttons en esta página
    InstallTypePageID := InstallTypePage.ID;
    InstallTypePage.Add('Instalar');
    InstallTypePage.Add('Reparar');
    InstallTypePage.Add('Desinstalar'); 
  end;
```

Comment: gracias, es lo que estaba buscando.