# Acceder a los datos de un radio button en Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Cree una página basada en una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/88616/36135) de mi pregunta [¿Cómo crear una página de opciones en Inno Setup?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88612/c%C3%B3mo-crear-una-p%C3%A1gina-de-opciones-en-inno-setup),  lo único que no entiendo es como agarrar el que esta seleccionado para crear la condición.
Alguien podría explicarme cómo hacerlo?

Aqui dejo mi codigo:

```
InstallTypePage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpSelectDir,'Texto1', 'Texto2', 'Texto3', True, False);

    //Crea los radio buttons en esta página
    InstallTypePageID := InstallTypePage.ID;
    InstallTypePage.Add('Instalar');
    InstallTypePage.Add('Reparar');
    InstallTypePage.Add('Desinstalar');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se accede de la siguiente manera:

```
InstallTypePage.Values[0] //Instalar
InstallTypePage.Values[1] //Reparar
InstallTypePage.Values[2] //Desinstalar
```

Por ejemplo si deseas crear una condicion dependiendo del valor seleccionado seria:

```
if(InstallTypePage.Values[0] = True) then
  begin
    //Aqui el codigo que quieres ejecutar
  end;
```

Comment: gracias me funciono